# debug android app on chromebook

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc, androidappsonchromeos

I have an android app that works on the chromebook flip when using arc welder to install and run it.   However, when I download the current version from the play store, or sideload the current dev version by copying over the apk, the app doesn't run.  I get the splash screen and then a white screen and nothing happens.

I tried using chrome on the chromebook and doing chrome://inspect/#devices and chrome://inspect/#apps but i don't see my running app in either place. (The app is mostly a webview wrapping a JS application, so this is typically how I debug it).   I also tried using the android chrome browser and also do not see my app there.  I am not sure where to find the application logs, although I did try looking at the various system logs.   The chromebook is in developer mode so I can get a shell and look around, but I couldn't find an app log.   adb devices does not show my app, and adb logcat doesn't show anything either.

Anyone know how to debug a webview app on the chromebook?

Comment: Note that support for the ARC Welder may be discontinued, given that Google is going in a different direction for Android apps on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use ARC Welder anymore. Play Store can be installed directly on Chromebook.

Also remote debugging using ADB is possible. Follow instructions from here.
https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html

Comment: Plenty of Chromebooks still do not support the Play Store, making ARC Welder the only option.  Here's the official list of supported devices: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps